# Writing files in a loop - JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I seem to be having an issue when trying to write to a file in a loop, the loop is iterating even though the first file has not been created (I think i am either not understanding promises or the asynchronous nature of the script)

So on the command line i will run `node write_file_script.js premier_league`

```
// teams.js
module.exports = {
premier_league: [
  { team_name: "Team 1", friendly_name: "name 1"},
  { team_name: "Team 2", friendly_name: "name 2"}
 ]
}
```

My Script

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const TEAM = require('./teams');

const Excel = require('exceljs');
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

for (var team = 0; team < TEAM[args].length; team++) {
  console.log("Starting Excel File generation for " + TEAM[args][team]['team_name']);
  var fhcw = require('../data_files/home/fhcw/' + TEAM[args][team]['friendly_name'] + '_home' + '.json');
  fhcw = fhcw.map(Number);

  workbook.xlsx.readFile('./excel_files/blank.xlsx')
  .then(function() {
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    // Write FHCW
    for (i=0; i < fhcw.length; i++) {
      col = i+6;
      worksheet.getCell('E'+ col).value = fhcw[i];
    }

    console.log(TEAM[args][team])
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./excel_files/' + TEAM[args] + '/' + TEAM[args][team]['friendly_name'] + '.xlsx');

  });

}
```

The output i get when running this is

```
Starting Excel File generation for Team 1
Starting Excel File generation for Team 2
undefined
(node:75393) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'friendly_name' of undefined
```

So it seems like the file is not being written but the loop continues, how can i ensure the file is written before moving onto the next loop?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for writing a file: https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#writing-csv
You can see that there is a .then function which tells you when the writing of the file is done

Comment: Thanks, but seem to get same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is returning a `Promise`, and you want to do them serially (one at a time) instead of in parallel (start all at the same time), you'll need to wait for each before you start the next using `then()`.

Also, note that your `TEAM` is just an export of an array (at least as presented), so you can't give it `args`, which is where the other error comes from.

When you have a list of things to do, the best way to do them is to have a queue which you run until you run out of files. In this case, it looks like your `TEAM` array is your queue, but since this is an export, I'd recommend not necessarily changing this, but instead copy it to another array which you can alter:

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const TEAM = require('./teams');

const Excel = require('exceljs');
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

const writeNextFile = (queue) => {
  // If we have nothing left in the queue, we're done.
  if (!queue.length) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  const team = queue.shift(); // get the first element, take it out of the array

  console.log("Starting Excel File generation for " + team.team_name);
  var fhcw = require('../data_files/home/fhcw/' + team.friendly_name + '_home' + '.json');
  fhcw = fhcw.map(Number);

  // return this promise chain
  return workbook.xlsx.readFile('./excel_files/blank.xlsx')
  .then(function() {
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    // Write FHCW
    for (i=0; i < fhcw.length; i++) {
      col = i+6;
      worksheet.getCell('E'+ col).value = fhcw[i];
    }

    console.log(team);
    // not sure what you thought this would TEAM[args] would have translated to, but it wouldn't have been a string, so I put ??? for now
    // also, making the assumption that writeFile() returns a Promise.
    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./excel_files/' + team.??? + '/' + team.friendly_name + '.xlsx');
  }).then(() => writeNextFile(queue));
}

writeNextFile(TEAM.slice(0)) // make a copy of TEAM so we can alter it
  .then(() => console.log('Done'))
  .catch(err => console.error('There was an error', err));
```

Basically, our function takes an array and will write the first team, then call itself recursively to call the next. Eventually it'll all resolve and you're end up with is a Promise that resolves at the end.

When it comes to Promises, you basically always need to chain them together. You won't be able to use a for loop for them, or any other standard loop for that matter.

If you wanted to write them all at once, it is a little cleaner, because you can just do a non-recursive map for each and use `Promise.all` to know when they are done.

```
const writeNextFile = (team) => {
  console.log("Starting Excel File generation for " + team.team_name);
  var fhcw = require('../data_files/home/fhcw/' + team.friendly_name + '_home' + '.json');
  fhcw = fhcw.map(Number);

  // return this promise chain
  return workbook.xlsx.readFile('./excel_files/blank.xlsx')
  .then(function() {
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    // Write FHCW
    for (i=0; i < fhcw.length; i++) {
      col = i+6;
      worksheet.getCell('E'+ col).value = fhcw[i];
    }

    console.log(team);
    // not sure what you thought this would TEAM[args] would have translated to, but it wouldn't have been a string, so I put ??? for now
    // also, making the assumption that writeFile() returns a Promise.
    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./excel_files/' + team.??? + '/' + team.friendly_name + '.xlsx');
  });
}

Promise.all(TEAM.map(writeTeamFile))
  .then(() => console.log('Done')
  .catch(err => console.error('Error'));
```

Promises are for async, and generally when you have a group of things, you want to do them in parallel because it's faster. That's why the parallel version is a lot cleaner; we don't have to call things recursively.

Comment: I have a question around your statement of `Also, note that your TEAM is just an export of an array (at least as presented), so you can't give it args, which is where the other error comes from.` if i run `node script.js premier_league` then my argument is `premier_league` which gives me access to that object within TEAM, for some reason i thought that it would translate to the string `premier_league` but that is obviously incorrect

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood what you were going for there. Yes, if `args` is 'premier_league`, then you are correct that you should use `args` there... sorta. Instead of `process.argv.slice(2)` just do `process.argv[2]` or else you'll have an array which wouldn't make sense. However, the bit where I did `teams.???` still doesn't make sense. In that case, you'd probably just want `args` instead of `teams[args]`.

Comment: well i have just added `league:` key now to the JSON object so can just reference `team.league`.. so your answer works (serial version) with a small amendment `const writeNextFile = function(queue)`, was getting an error without.

Comment: Haha, it's no problem, really appreciate the time you took in answering in such a detailed way :-), just wish i could understand these things more

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not writing to the same file, you can loop through the files and perform read/write operations.

You can bind the index value in the loop, and move ahead.

Example code.

```
var filesWrittenCount = 0;

for(var team = 0; team < TEAM[args].length; team++){
    (function(t){
        // call your async function here. 
        workbook.xlsx.readFile('./excel_files/blank.xlsx').then(function() {
            var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
            // Write FHCW
            for (i=0; i < fhcw.length; i++) {
                col = i+6;
                worksheet.getCell('E'+ col).value = fhcw[i];
            }

            console.log(TEAM[args][t])
            workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./excel_files/' + TEAM[args] + '/' + TEAM[args][t]['friendly_name'] + '.xlsx');

            // update number of files written.
            filesWrittenCount++;

            if (totalFiles == filesWrittenCount) {
                // final callback function - This states that all files are updated
                done();
            }

        });
    }(team));
}

function done() {
    console.log('All data has been loaded');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `writeFile()` also returns a Promise, so it'd have to be inside of that. It also looks like they want write one file a time. If that's the case, this won't do that. It fires them all off in parallel, which there are cleaner approaches for.

Comment: If they are writing different files, I don't see a reason for serializing them. They might have a use-case for that.

Comment: Nor do I, but their question was about having one complete before the other. Even if you are going to parallelize with Promises, you should make use of Promise.all instead of counters and callbacks.

Comment: Thank you both for answering, im going to go through them and try to get some understanding.  Im not sure it makes a difference at present if i do them parallel or serially as i don't have many files to create, however the more this increases in parallel will obviously have its benefits